# Parse data from OpenWeatherMap, using retrofit2 and rxJava2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I've started to learn Retrofit and RxJava, and I've decided to create weatherApp. Now my goal is to retrieve weather data from OpenWeatherMap Api. Here's my code:
For api:

```
package com.example.aldres.workingwithapis.Api;

import com.example.aldres.workingwithapis.models.WeatherData;

import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;
import rx.Observable;

public interface Api {
    @GET("weather?")
    Observable<WeatherData> getWeatherData(@Query("q") String city);
}
```

Also code for my WeatherData model:

```
package com.example.aldres.workingwithapis.models;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class WeatherData {

    @SerializedName("coord")
    @Expose
    private Coord coord;
    @SerializedName("weather")
    @Expose
    private List<Weather> weather = null;
    @SerializedName("base")
    @Expose
    private String base;
    @SerializedName("main")
    @Expose
    private Main main;
    @SerializedName("visibility")
    @Expose
    private Integer visibility;
    @SerializedName("wind")
    @Expose
    private Wind wind;
    @SerializedName("clouds")
    @Expose
    private Clouds clouds;
    @SerializedName("dt")
    @Expose
    private Integer dt;
    @SerializedName("sys")
    @Expose
    private Sys sys;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("cod")
    @Expose
    private Integer cod;

    public Coord getCoord() {
        return coord;
    }

    public void setCoord(Coord coord) {
        this.coord = coord;
    }

    public List<Weather> getWeather() {
        return weather;
    }

    public void setWeather(List<Weather> weather) {
        this.weather = weather;
    }

    public String getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    public void setBase(String base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public Main getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public Integer getVisibility() {
        return visibility;
    }

    public void setVisibility(Integer visibility) {
        this.visibility = visibility;
    }

    public Wind getWind() {
        return wind;
    }

    public void setWind(Wind wind) {
        this.wind = wind;
    }

    public Clouds getClouds() {
        return clouds;
    }

    public void setClouds(Clouds clouds) {
        this.clouds = clouds;
    }

    public Integer getDt() {
        return dt;
    }

    public void setDt(Integer dt) {
        this.dt = dt;
    }

    public Sys getSys() {
        return sys;
    }

    public void setSys(Sys sys) {
        this.sys = sys;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getCod() {
        return cod;
    }

    public void setCod(Integer cod) {
        this.cod = cod;
    }

}
```

And also my mainActivity:

```
package com.example.aldres.workingwithapis;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.aldres.workingwithapis.Api.Api;
import com.example.aldres.workingwithapis.models.WeatherData;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;
import rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView middleText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        middleText = findViewById(R.id.middleText);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/")
                .build();
        Api apiService = retrofit.create(Api.class);

        Observable<WeatherData> observable = apiService.getWeatherData("London");

                observable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<WeatherData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(WeatherData weatherData) {
                        middleText.setText(weatherData.getWind());
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

At this point, my app should display string with wind parameter into my TextView middleText, but when I start my app, it starts without any errors, but I don't have my text in the TextView. What have I done wrong?

Comment: mind including the errors ?

Comment: There's no errors in my logcat, that's a problem.

Comment: you should use `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`. does your api need a key? http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/London??

Comment: Api call should be: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather/q={my city name}. I've changed  `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())` to 
`.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` but it's still the same.

Comment: have you changed your `middleText` visibility in xml to invisible or gone, by default?

Comment: I haven't set it to invisible. My TextView looks like:
    `<TextView
        android:id="@+id/middleText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="" />`

Answer (score 2):

Your request is probably erroring out without you knowing about it as you ignore the onError method.
Add `e.printStackTrace()` to that method to see if this is the case.

Comment: Oh, I see, i get `retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.HttpException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized`

Comment: I see, I need an api key, which I didn't notice. That's my problem, I think. Where should I add apiKey in my app?

Comment: @Aldres yes you need api key **api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&APPID=1111111111** besides switching to `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` cause its a blocking call

Comment: Oh, I see now. I found my api key, what's the best way to change my query, so it will contain api key?

Comment: @Aldres Like `Observable<WeatherData> getWeatherData(@Query("q") String city,@Query("APPID") String yourkey);`!

Comment: Oh yes! It works! I was searching for a problem for few days, because I was thinking, that problem was in my using of RxJava or Retrofit, but answer was so easy. Thank you again. With Api key it works just fine.